# Count alpha characters in string field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1. I have column in a database table that contains alphanumeric strings. I need to count the letters in the string and produce a table of the aggregate results showing the number of letters by a count of the records which had that number of letters in the column.

I am also trying, if possible, to make the list dynamic so the rows in the aggregated results goes as far as the max number of letters in a string in the table column.

The examples I have found so far look to scan the string character by character which will be very performance intensive and I have also looked at the replace function but it does not look like it works with regex and I would have to replace each letter in the alphabet in turn.

Thanks for any help.

For example: Table1

```
ID
----------
A00001
AB0001
AC123
CB00AD
1234AD
```

Aggregated results:

```
No of letters          Count of records
-----------            -----------        
1                      1
2                      3
3                      0
4                      1
```

Comment: So please explain what you did so far?

Comment: For the best performance you would determine the count at the point of insertion/update, store that value in a column then simply query on that.  All other approaches are going to require scanning the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A00001')
,('AB0001')
,('AC123')
,('CB00AD')
,('1234AD')

Select Letters
      ,Cnt = count(*)
 From (    
        Select Letters = count(*)
         From  @YourTable A
         Join (
                Select Top (select max(len(ID)) from @YourTable) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1
         ) B  on n<=len(ID)
         Where substring(ID,N,1) not like '[0-9]'
         Group By ID
       ) A
 Group By Letters
```

**Returns**

```
Letters Cnt
1       1
2       3
4       1
```

Comment: Excellent as always.... but this doesn't return a 3 with a 0-count per the OP's example.

Comment: @AlanBurstein Thanks,  I did consider that, but what would be the cap... Max witnessed?  500?   A simple left join as you did  +1 would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

A trivial method is based on replace

```
SELECT LEN(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE( 
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE( 
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(myColumn, '0', ''),
   '1',''),
   '2',''),
   '3',''),
   '4',''),
   '5',''),
   '6',''),
   '7',''),
   '8',''),
   '9','')
) num_char
from  your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You could benefit from the performance of an Inline Table-Valued Function to perform the count. If you can understand the code of the function, you can use the tally table to generate the empty rows if needed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountChars(
    @String varchar(8000),
    @Pattern varchar(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN(@String)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT COUNT(*) CharCount
FROM cteTally
WHERE SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1) LIKE @Pattern

GO

SELECT CharCount, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY dbo.CountChars( ID, '[A-Za-Z]')
GROUP BY CharCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [NGrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) you could do this:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @table VALUES ('A00001'),('AB0001'),('AC123'),('CB00AD'),('1234AD');

-- Solution
WITH l(C) AS
(
  SELECT      Letters = SUM(PATINDEX('[A-Z]',ng.token))
  FROM        @table               AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(t.ID,1) AS ng
  GROUP BY    t.ID
)
SELECT    Letters     = t.N, 
          RecordCount = COUNT(l.C)
FROM      (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) AS t(N)
LEFT JOIN l ON t.N = l.C
GROUP BY  t.N;
```

**Returns:**

```
Letters     RecordCount
----------- -----------
1           1
2           3
3           0
4           1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, scalar function performance...giving you a function to strip all non-Alpha chars from string. Take len() off the return. Other comments are correct, this is not good performance wise.

```sql
Create Function dbo.AlphaOnly ( @inStr varchar(max) )
    Returns varchar(max)
as
    Begin
        Declare @curLoc int
        Set @curLoc = PatIndex('%[^A-Za-z]%', @inStr)
        While @curLoc > 0
            Begin
                Set @inStr = Stuff(@inStr,@curLoc,1,'')
                Set @curLoc = PatIndex('%[^A-Za-z]%', @inStr)
            End
        Return @inStr
    End
GO
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, however, scalar functions aren't great performers I'm afraid (unless you make an inline scalar function in 2019), and a `WHILE` loop is a really bad way to do things in SQL Server for something that could far more easily be performed with a set based method. SQL Server excels at set based methods, but is awful at iterative tasks, and a loop like this falls in the latter.

Comment: Dang! AS you know, scalar UDF performance is terrible - using max data type (varchar(max)) makes it even worse. This can be done inline, see: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/digitsonlyee-and-alphanumericonly

Comment: I cast a downvote here. Why? Because scalar functions are horrible for performance. You know this and posted it as an answer anyway even stating such in your answer. Providing a bad approach and stating that you know it isn't a good approach will earn a downvote from me everytime. Alan and Larnu should have downvoted this too for the same reason.

Comment: and I said as much when I put it posted it. busy days, didn't have time to work out either a table valued function or windowed solution...